# How to remove the group separator?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

```
<customcontrol:GridStyleInfo HorizontalAlignment="Center" CellType="IntegerEdit">
  <customcontrol:GridStyleInfo.NumberFormat>
    <numberFormat:NumberFormatInfo  NumberGroupSeparator='?'/>
</customcontrol:GridStyleInfo.NumberFormat>
```

- input : 60023
- actual output : 60,023
- Expected : 60023

How to avoid the numeric separator by using the number-format?

Answer (score 0):

Just make it an empty string:

```
<numberFormat:NumberFormatInfo  NumberGroupSeparator=""/>
```